# Unexpected token error when using Gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to run a task in Gulp and I'm having problems running on Linux. The task doesn't seem to be working correctly

```
function jsTask() {
    return gulp.src('./frontend/src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dvest('frontend/js'));
}

gulp.task('js', jsTask);
gulp.task('js-watch', () => {
    return watch('./frontend/src/js/**/*.js', { ignoreInitial: false }, jsTask);
});

function lessTask() {
    return gulp.src(['./frontend/src/less/*-main.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
}

gulp.task('less', lessTask);
gulp.task('less-watch', () => {
    return watch('./frontend/src/less/**/*.less', { ignoreInitial: false }, lessTask);
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'less']);
gulp.task('watch', ['js-watch', 'less-watch']);
```

When I run the `gulp js` command, I get the following error below

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: /var/www/myproject/frontend/src/js/iframe.js: 
   9 |
  10 | export const routes = (
> 11 |     <Route path="" component={({children}) => (children) }>
     |     ^
  12 |         <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFoundPage} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Babel to transpile your JSX and ES2015 code. Babel uses certain presets to transpile your code to pure JavaScript but you aren't passing any so the code isn't being transpiled to pure JavaScript. Thus, it raises a syntax error because the JSX isn't valid JavaScript.

You're just using `gulp-babel` as `babel()` without any presets so it won't transpile your code. You need to tell Babel to use certain presets First, install the presets applicable to you:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

These commands will install the appropriate presets to transpile your code, for ES2015 and React. Then apply them to your `gulpfile` as options to your `babel`:

```
return gulp.src('./frontend/src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/js'));
```

Also, make sure to use `gulp.dest` not `gulp.dvest`. This should transpile your code correctly.

Comment: @Dennis if it worked please consider accepting the answer for future readers by hitting the checkmark to the left of the answer. I'm glad it was helpful :)